# How to adjust text size in ggsankey plot while keeping label text centered

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to adjust all fonts in my ggsankey plot, but I cant seem to figure out how, I also have some issues with text centering in the label.

I have this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Before = c("Poor", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Normal",
             "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor"),
  After = c("Poor", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal",
            "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal",
            "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate",
            "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor",
            "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate",
            "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor",
            "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate",
            "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal",
            "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor",
            "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor","Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor")
)


transition_counts <-  data %>% make_long(Before, After)

# Create Sankey plot
ggplot(transition_counts, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .6,
              node.color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size=3,color = "white", fill = "gray40", hjust = -0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 10) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")  +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

which gives this:

[image]

I want to make the text a little smaller so I tried `theme_sankey(base_size = 8)`, which gives this where only axis and legend text change

[image]

I went ahead and also changed to `geom_sankey_label(size=1,color = "white", fill = "gray40", hjust = -0.2)` which makes the label text smaller but the smaller I make it the text is not centered in the label anymore.

[image]

How can I adjust all text sizes while keeping the label text centered in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `hjust` to shift your labels nudge the `x` position of your labels directly:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)

transition_counts <- data %>% make_long(Before, After)

# Create Sankey plot
ggplot(
  transition_counts,
  aes(
    x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node,
    next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node),
    label = node
  )
) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = .6,
    node.color = "gray30"
  ) +
  geom_sankey_label(
    aes(x = as.numeric(x) + .05),
    size = 4 / .pt, color = "white", fill = "gray40",
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 4) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

[image]